# The “Close” button for the snippet “Full page” doesn’t work when site isolation is enabled

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-snippets, user-experience, firefox

If you create a snippet in a question or an answer and click on “Full page” then the “Close” button is not clickable. Am I the only one to whom this happens? This was tested in Firefox, Safari and Chrome on macOS. In Firefox, this is reproducible when Fission (Site isolation) is enabled.

Here’s a test snippet; try it out:

```html
Press "Run code snippet" and press "full page" on the top right corner. The close button won't work
```

Comment: No repro, FF 94.0 on Linux Mint

Comment: Odd; it seems to work for me in Firefox and Chrome on Windows.

Comment: No Repro Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 in Ubuntu

Comment: @CodyGray there isn't even a cursor when hovering and i have to refresh the page

Comment: Anything on the console or you have any extensions that messing with it?

Comment: @SurajRao nope, nothing

Comment: No Repro Microsoft Edge Windows.

Comment: I’m always able to reproduce this on Firefox Nightly, but not on Chrome. Noticed this for a long time, but was never confident enough to report this. I always assumed it was a minor browser bug. I have a hunch that this is somehow security related: maybe to prevent clicking on invisible links or in invisible iframes?

Comment: I just realized that in a different Firefox install, it works. Now I need to find which `about:config` setting is responsible…

Comment: No repro in Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit), Edge Version 95.0.1020.53 (Official build) (64-bit), Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: To add to the list: no repro on Opera 81.0.4196.37 on W10. Starts to sound like it is only present on MacOS

Comment: Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. On bug reports, voting can represent people being able to reproduce the issue, or not. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta should not be automatically considered to mean that there are problems with the post. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the post quality is good.

Comment: @OlegValter No. I’m using Linux. This appears to be some browser setting that I haven’t had the time to figure out yet.

Comment: Got it. Enabling Fission (Site isolation) in Firefox causes this issue. 100 % reproducible.

Comment: @SebastianSimon MacOS is not that far from Linux :) Odd that fission makes this reproducible...

Comment: @Makyen okay, sorry i didn't know that. I'm pretty new to the meta site

Comment: Thanks to @Sebastian's comment I made a [min repro](https://jsfiddle.net/u35qz9nc/) for FF with Fission. Some observations: the server response seems to be a trigger, [using jsfiddle's echo service](https://jsfiddle.net/tLmkpd5v/) instead of stacksnippet's doesn't reproduce (nor does using things like srcdoc etc.). Having [the overlay out by a px](https://jsfiddle.net/wfoLnbyh/) doesn't trigger the issue (so `.popin{padding-top:5px;top:-1px;}` would workaround it). However this only concerns Fission, I doubt OP faced the same issue on their other browsers and that they share the same triggers.

Comment: Probably https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1747409

Comment: Confirm problem. I can't close full page code snippet. Firefox 95.0.2 Windows 10 x64.

Comment: To work around this issue, I added the following CSS to the adjustments I apply to SO/SE: `.snippet-box-result[style] { padding-top: 1.5em; }` The `.snippet-box-result` `<iframe>` only has a `style` attribute when in full page mode, so this doesn't affect the snippet when it's displayed within the post (i.e. when it's not in full page mode).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1747409), and Firefox version 97 or 98 will include a fix for this. There is nothing wrong with the code on Stack Overflow's end.

If anyone else encounters this issue in another browser, then that's still a mystery.

Comment: Firefox 97.0 on Windows fixes this for me.