# Is this Moment.js plugin broken, or are Stack Snippets not working?

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

I was updating my self-answer to *[Filter out non-contiguous date using momentjs and twix.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725549/filter-out-non-contiguous-date-using-momentjs-and-twix-js)* and tried to make use of [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info), but it's not working.

I'm trying to understand if the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) plugin is broken, I'm doing something wrong, or Stack Snippets aren't behaving as intended (or the setup of my work laptop/Internet proxy has broken something else).

The error I get in the snippet console is:

```json
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).twix is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 25,
  "colno": 43
}
```

And in the developer console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_twix')
> at Function.Twix._extend (twix.min.js:1)
> at makeTwix (twix.min.js:1)
> at twix.min.js:1
> at twix.min.js:1

Which, I could have sworn, was not there last night. It might hint this is *not* a snippet problem.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413126/6296561

Comment: Yes, the `twix` library also fails to initialise. Throws an error because `first` is undefined. But I don't see a good reason it should be right now. EDIT: `Twix._extend(moment._locale, { _twix: Twix.defaults });` seems to be a aproblem because `moment._locale` is `undefined`. Perhaps the source of `moment` needs to include that? Dunno.

Comment: @VLAZ it exists [in the codebase](https://github.com/moment/moment/search?q=_locale) for moment, but I've not dug into if it would be accessible in the way twix seems to assume it is

Comment: The version of twix.js you use seems quite old (now they are at 1.3.0). Updating it it will merge correctly with moment.js, leaving only a TypeError about `range.start.unix` being undefined, but that error comes from your code. (I don't know twix.js to know if there should be such a property or not).

Comment: @Kaiido that fixed it, I assumed the cdn would default to the latest version

Comment: I've deleted the answer as it's currently incorrect for the recent version of twix